# How to get the user_id from mysql using procedural php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am an android/java developer and Im struggling with php.
I've made it as far as inserting a new user in the DB, now I want to get their ID.

What do I do with the result? I want to assign it to a variable.

```
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = '" . $user_email . "'";
$result =
```

PS: Im using mysql, not mysqli.

EDIT: Here is what I did:

```
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = '" . $user_email ."';";
$store_info = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)); 
$user_id = $store_info['user_id'];
$response["message"] = "User created with id: " . $user_id;
echo json_encode($response);
```

And the error message after inserting (successfully) the user in the db:

```
null{"success":3,"message":"User created with id: "}
```

Comment: I added a new answer: you have a syntax error in SQL

Comment: [Please, stop using mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1238019) in new code, they are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Instead of, have a look on [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), and use [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: I just wanted to get my api up and running quickly. When I do that I will start learning php and mysqli and pdo. Just wanted quick results so I can motivate myself

Comment: @J.Kowalski So, you got an empty result from the database. Does user with this email exist in the database? Can you show us the dump?

Comment: INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `user_name`, `user_email`, `user_password`, `user_sex`, `user_avatar`, `user_date_registered`, `user_last_seen`, `user_points`) VALUES (18, 'asd', 'asd2e', 'kirobr', '', '', '2013-10-31 08:22:12', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0);

Comment: @J.Kowalski I don't see any email in your query

Comment: well I just inserted some random symbols (the debugging form has no validation) for testing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that your are using MySQLi API

```
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = '$user_email'"; //Your Query

$store_info = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, $query)); 
//Execute the query, fetch the result, it's just one result so no need for a while loop

echo $store_info['user_id']; //echo id
```

---

As per the comments, you requested a `mysql_()` version so here you go...

```
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = '$user_email'"; //Your Query

$store_info = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)); 
//Execute the query, fetch the result, it's just one result so no need for a while loop

echo $store_info['user_id']; //echo id
```

Still consider using [`mysqli_()`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Why? Because [`mysql_()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is now deprecated, read the red box on the documentation page which says...

[image]

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) answer for PDO tutorial

Comment: @J.Kowalski Remove the `i` from function and connection variable, rest stays the same, but I would like to suggest you to use mysqli or pdo

Comment: @J.Kowalski  Better to start of with mysqli as mysql is deprecated.

Comment: Added quotes around `$user_email` to fix the syntax typo

Comment: @J.Kowalski Did you used my query? Your query has `= =`

Comment: fixed that and now Im getting user ID = FALSE

Comment: I guess you are not paying attention to the answer. This answer is different from what you `tried` in your edit.

Comment: but I dont have mysqli installed or whatever is needed for it to be used. And I've setup my connection via mysql not mysqli. I really dont know php :(

Comment: @J.Kowalski Also, you need to check the id you are using to fetch the row, also this is wrong again `$response["user_id"]`

Comment: @J.Kowalski Just remove the `i` from the functions and remove `$connection, ` part, yes the space after the comma too, so it will be `mysqli_query($query)`

Comment: @Mr.Alien since He is cofused about MySQL and MySQLi, I think it will make your answer even better if you add an example for him using `mysql_*` as well

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky actually I was ignoring, that will just spread the disease, I guess I need to add it now..

Answer (score 3):

Here is the PDO variant:

```
<?php
//credentials
$host = 'localhost';
$user = "user";
$password = '';
$db_name = 'test';
$port = 3306;

//connection to the database
try
{
    $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;port=$port;dbname=$db_name", $user, $password);
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

//prepare and execute SELECT statement
$sth = $connection->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = :email");
$sth->execute(array(':email' => $user_email));

$record = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print $record["user_id"];
```

Comment: do I need to install something in order to use PDO?

Comment: @J.Kowalski Usually this library is shipped together with PHP. Does my code run for you?

Comment: @J.Kowalski Look for extension=pdo.so in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

If you use mysql (but you shouldn't, it's deprecated) :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = '$user_email'");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // you result (id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Connection:

```
define("HOST","localhost");
define("USER","mysql_username");
define("PASS","password");

$conn = mysql_connect(HOST,USER,PASS) or die("<h3>Sorry, could not connect to MySQL. Please Try Again</h3>");
$db = mysql_select_db(DBNAME,$conn) or die("<h3>Sorry, could not connect to Database. Please Try Again</h3>")
```

Query:

```
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = = '" . $user_email . "'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error comes because of the error in SQL query: you used `=` operator twice:

```
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = = '" . $user_email . "'";
```

Must be:

```
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email = '" . $user_email . "'";
```